# Show user before and after results when doing an update in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an T-SQL Script and in this script I perform several typical updates:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET column01 = value01, column02 = value02, ..., columnN = valueN;

UPDATE TABLE2 SET column01 = value01, column02 = value02, ..., columnN = valueN;

UPDATE TABLE3 SET column01 = value01, column02 = value02, ..., columnN = valueN;
```

So I would like for each table update above, to show user the values before and after update it, that is, show user a table result consisting on two rows, first row corresponding the values before doing the update and second one corresponding the values after updating.

So how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to get the before and after states, like so:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET column01 = value01, column02 = value02, ..., columnN = valueN;
OUTPUT
deleted.*, inserted.*;
```

You can write the result from the `OUTPUT` clause into a temporary table or table variable, and then select the columns from source and target table as 2 rows using union all, as shown in the demo.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/AAC3987)

Comment: but is it returning only the columns updated or all the columns for the row updated? I would like only the columns updated for the row.

Comment: If you know what you are updating, you can just include those columns. Play around with the demo to get a feel of it. http://rextester.com/SOG85653

Comment: ok, great, but instead of concatenating in the same row, is it not possible to put them in different row?

Comment: @user1624552 I have updated my answer. Please look at the new demo link.